# Data management with Python base on vlookup function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I am trying to transform a data matrix in Python.

I want to change from :

```
 Well A B C D

Production 1 2 3 4
```

to

```
Well  Production 

A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
```

It is a simple task in Excel but I would like to know how to do it in Python.

How do I do it? I am sure there is a very simple way to do it but I just have not come across it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend setting index to `Well` before transposing. Transposing first you'll be left with a random column `0` and Production will become an observation in the dataframe.

```
df.T
               0 # this is your column
Well  Production # this becomes an observation
A              1
B              2
C              3
D              4
```

Do this:

```
df.set_index('Well').T
Well  Production
A              1
B              2
C              3
D              4
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is contained in a dataframe you can simply transpose it.

```
data = data.transpose()
```

or equivalently

```
data = data.T
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your records into csv list format

```
l1 = [ 'Well', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ]
l2 = [ 'Production', '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
for i,j in zip(l1, l2):
    print ('%s %4s' %(i,j))
```

Output:

```
Well Production
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
```